# Perform some clean up action when form window closed

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

How do I run some clean up code when a user closes a window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Subscribe to [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event (if you are using WinForms and not WPF).

Answer (score 4):

You can hook up to the [`Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) event on your window (if you are using WPF).

Comment: The event is actually called `FormClosing` to be accurate ;)

Comment: @Øyvind Bråthen, not in WPF. Check the link for yourself ;-)

Comment: Since the OP didn't state WPF or not, I will have to say *touché*. You got me there. I'll even throw in a +1 for good measure. ;)

Comment: @Øyvind Bråthen, hehe thanks. But I don't think *I* got you. You got yourself ;-)